# JavaScript: Is there a reason that console.log works but not return?

Tags: javascript, return, iif-function

I am trying to get a checkbox to return 1 or 0 depending upon if it is checked or not. I am having a hard time understanding why the return in this if function is not working. If I used console.log instead of return the output is correct. 1 when checked 0 when unchecked. with return, checked is skipped and it only returns the else statement, so it is 0 either checked or unchecked. I am new to coding in general so I am sure I am missing something simple here. Any ideas? Thanks!

```js
document.getElementById("materialLoaded").addEventListener('input', materialCheck);

function materialCheck() {

    if (this.checked) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the return supossed to do?

Comment: Where is it supposed to return to? You are telling the browser: please run this function in the **future** when there is an input event. The result appears long after you call `addEventListener`

Comment: `console.log` will log to the console (as the name suggests) while `return` just ends the function and passes the value to whatever called that function. Since you're not using that return value, you won't see anything but it *is* produced.

Comment: This feels like an X/Y problem.

Comment: Yes I guess this is an X/Y problem. I am trying to get an HTML element to change from red to green when three checkboxes are checked. So what I am trying to do with the return is pass on the new value of a checkbox every time a new input is registered so I can use the value in another function that will change the color of an HTML element when all three checkboxes are checked. That's my thought anyway. This could be the completely wrong way to approach something like this but I thought I would try it and see where it goes.

Comment: This is indeed completely the wrong way to go about this. The return value of an event listener is not put "somewhere" for you to access. If you want to use that value, your best bet is to directly do it, e.g., `foo(1)` or `foo(0)` instead of returning. This is exactly what is happening when you call `console.log'. If you need to change something, then you need to invoke a function that makes that change as part of the event listener call. You could use something like the observable design pattern to introduce a level of indirection to the call but it will require other kind of setup.

Comment: Alright that helps out a lot. Looks like I should spend some time understanding javascript structure and observable design patterns. Thanks VLAZ and others for the help!

Answer (score 0):

sure thing you won't be seeing anything because ur not telling your program to tell u anything.
you're telling it to return a value In a function but to see the value it returned u have to call the function.
for example to see ur return value call the function using your window:

```
 document.getElementById("materialLoaded").addEventListener('input', materialCheck);

function materialCheck() {

if (this.checked) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}

window.alert(materialCheck());
 }
```

javascript is object oriented, u can't write a function and it should work by itself, it has to be called.
console.log works because there's an object there which is the console calling the function for example or displaying what u asked for(ex: console.log("hello"))

Comment: Now I understand. Sorry I actually just left the call function out of the code provided in the question. I was manually telling the console to run materialCheck() and forgot to add it to the code itself for the example. still, it does not return anything which is the part I am confused about.

Comment: @maccollaflower let me explain,
basically "return" gives you a value (return a value) but doesn't display it on your screen unlike console.log which display the value returned in your console

Answer (score 0):

You said in the comments you want to chek to see how many checkboxes are checked. So add an event listener to the checkboxes (or use event delegation) and check to see how many are checked with a simple selector.

Basic concept:

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");

const validateCheckboxes = function() {
  const checked = document.querySelectorAll(".chk:checked");
  const isValid = checked.length === 3;
  wrapper.classList.toggle("valid", isValid);
};

wrapper.addEventListener("change", validateCheckboxes);
```

```css
.valid {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" />
</div>
```

Comment: My gosh haha that is so much cleaner and simpler than what I was trying to do. Also makes so much more sense. Thanks epascarello!